# C++ Windows application menus stop responding

Tags: c++, windows

I'm an electrical engineer and am creating my first C++ Windows 10 application in Visual Studio.

When I start the app that I've created, and my application window starts with its menus, I can open a file and start processing that file. This processing takes several minutes and
can't be interrupted for too long (less than a millisecond - hopefully).

The problem I'm having is that when the file processing is underway my window's menus don't respond. This is tolerable when I'm running under the Visual Studio IDE, but when I run the standalone app's .exe file then the app's graphics soon stops rendering and Windows posts a "Not responding" error message.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to solve these related problems. There must be a simple way to temporarily give control back to WinMain or window_callback.

Here's a simplified structure of the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, ...) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            AddMenus(hwnd);
            break;
        case MY_FILE_OPEN:
            open_file(hwnd);
            break;
         ...
    }
}
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, ...) {

    // Create Window Class
    ...
    // Register Class
    ...
    // Create Window
    HWND window = CreateWindow(window_class.lpszClassName, L"My Window NAME", ...);
    hdc = GetDC(window);

    // My application's initialization code
    ...
    while (running) {
        MSG message;
        while (PeekMessage(&message, window, ...) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }
    }
}
void open_file(HWND hwnd) {
    here's where I call the file processing code (a several-minute loop);
}
```

Comment: It's not that simple, you have to start a new thread to do the work. Handle the synchronization/locking carefully.

Comment: Don't do time consuming job in GUI thread and most of GUI related functions are executed in GUI thread.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is not running the main message processing loop of `PeekMessage`, `TranslateMessage`, and `DispatchMessage` then it will become completely non-responsive as you have noticed.  That's the nature of message-driven event loops such as used by Windows.

You either need to run `open_file` in a different thread, or segment it in some way that it can process a small piece at a time and return and get called again to process another piece.

E.g.

```
    while (running) {
        MSG message;
        while (PeekMessage(&message, window, ...) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }
        open_file_piece();
    }
```

Comment: I got it working using a thread. I learned the difference between thread.join() and thread.detach(). The detach method was what I needed since my file-processing thread requires WinMain to continue running while the thread runs.